# How can I upgrade my smart contract or make it look better?

Tags: contract-deployment

[image]

I just finished building a smart contract using HumanStandardToken contract.

- Token Name: Test Network
- Symbol: TKN
- Decimals: 2
- Address : [0x49ad97585681ffd73Af9e371241899de5cFF7fc3](https://etherscan.io/address/0x49ad97585681ffd73Af9e371241899de5cFF7fc3#code).

Etherscan is showing me the message:

> Warning: The compiled contract might be susceptible to ZeroFunctionSelector (very low-severity), DelegateCallReturnValue (low-severity), ECRecoverMalformedInput................

I have no idea what it is. The reputation is UNKNOWN.

How can I resolve this problem and upgrade the reputation?

Comment: Are you a native-English speaker?

Comment: not to much , why!!

Answer (score 1):

If you click on each warning it will tell you what they mean.

Most of them have to do with bugs in the Solidity compiler and you can see many have been fixed in latest versions by following the links I mentioned above.

You are missing this line at the top of the file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4
```

Telling the compiler to use this version or above will remove many of these warnings.

Comment: I was using  ^0.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Here etherscan warns you about possible bugs in your smart contract. You can go through the warning descriptions provided by etherscan [here](https://etherscan.io/solcbuginfo) and find the functions that causes to produce the error and fix them.

Using a earlier version of compiler may remove warnings, but it's not a good practice. I think it's better to go with the latest stable version (since compiler also gets improved) `pragma solidity ^0.4.17;` and better to fix the code not to produce warnings.